# Celery worker exiting prematurely during Matplotlib subplot()

Tags: python, django, matplotlib, celery

I'm using Celery with django and django-celery-beat/django-celery-results.

Celery works fine up until it reaches this bit of code:
`figure, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,3))`
It then exits citing `signal 11`:

```
[2018-09-04 19:43:21,928: ERROR/MainProcess] Process 'ForkPoolWorker-1' pid:42611 exited with 'signal 11 (SIGSEGV)'
[2018-09-04 19:43:21,962: ERROR/MainProcess] Task handler raised error: WorkerLostError('Worker exited prematurely: signal 11 (SIGSEGV).',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/.local/share/virtualenvs/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/billiard/pool.py", line 1223, in mark_as_worker_lost
    human_status(exitcode)),
billiard.exceptions.WorkerLostError: Worker exited prematurely: signal 11 (SIGSEGV).
```

Know what might be happening?

Celery settings:

```
CACHE_LOCATION = "redis://%s:6379" % REDIS_HOST

CELERY_BROKER_URL = CACHE_LOCATION
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
```

versions:
billiard==3.5.0.4
celery==4.1.0

Comment: As per https://www.codechef.com/wiki/status-codes, SIGSEGV error could be caused by excessive memory usage. Have you tried plotting without using Celery?

Answer (score 4):

I know the question is a bit old but I experienced the same issue and found an easy solution. However it probably depends on what you want to do with `matplotlib` inside `celery`.

If like me you have a long running celery job that is computing some values that you want to plot in a **static image file**, then my answer should work.

Basically the issue comes from matplotlib's backends. As you can see in the documentation https://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-a-backend, you can choose the backend which will render the graphs. And you have *interactive* and *non-interactive* backends. If like me you want only to plot graphs and save them in static files you don't need the defaulted *interactive* backend.

For some unknown reason the default backend doesn't work on celery and raises a *SIGSEGV*, and thus what worked for me was to specify another backend at import time:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("Agg")
```

Hope this helps.